# Async call to WCF Service fails silently and randomly

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, web-services

I have been working on this issue for a few days now and can't seem to find a solution :(

I have an Asynchronous call to a WCF service which will work sometimes and on other occassions will do absolutely nothing - no call, no error, nothing. It will just stop after the execution of my calling method (main thread).
Breakpoints have been added to both the service method and in the auto-generated proxy class. If I am debugging on a failed call, these breakpoints will never be hit. Other times (when it happens to work) all break points will be hit.

I have completely removed the service and added it again, but still no luck.
I have even added a new service method and request message object in the hope that it was a freak problem with the original, however I am experiencing the same issue with the newly inserted method as well.

Just to note - This issue happens more often when I publish my application to a Virtual Machine. It doesn't happen so much on my local machine, however it still happens.

Here is an example of my code:-

This is the async call to the service;

```
ValidateUpdatesMessageRequest request = new ValidateUpdatesMessageRequest();
_serviceClient.ProcessUpdatesAsync(Request)
```

The service method looks like this;

```
public ValidateUpdatesMessageResponse ProcessUpdates(ValidateUpdatesMessageRequest request){ 
//method body 
}
```

I  also have an interface for the service which looks like this;

```
[OperationContract]
ValidateUpdatesMessageResponse ProcessUpdates(ValidateUpdatesMessageRequest request);
```

I would appreaciate ANY feedback whatsoever that may help steer me in the direction of a solution.

If you require any further info, please just let me know.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey @Dave we had some similar situation with SL and WCF services.. I donT know exactly the reason but making a high number of sequential calls to the service, especially when the operation on the server side is heavy, caused this kind of a behavior.. Is yours a similar case?

Comment: Can you post code and configuration of your service?

Comment: Hi @Zortkun, thanks for your response. There actually doesn't seem to be any pattern related with this issue. The call to the web service is to process records that have been / needing updated, so we may only be processing one record at a time and it will fail and other times we can process 20 records and it will work, or vice versa! What kind of steps have you taken to tackle the issue? Thanks.

Comment: @Dave I guess we came to a conclusion after reading this (http://forums.silverlight.net/t/174322.aspx/1/10) ...  then we started making the calls upon completion of each other.. :/ but I guess you wouldnT want that tho.

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, 

The call from the client side looks like this:-
   _serviceClient.ProcessUpdatesAsync(request)

The method in the service looks like this:-
   public ValidateUpdatesMessageResponse ProcessUpdates(ValidateUpdatesMessageRequest request)
{
//method body
}

I also have an interface for the service which looks like:-
   [OperationContract]
   ValidateUpdatesMessageResponse ProcessUpdates(ValidateUpdatesMessageRequest request);

Comment: Sorry @Rajesh, I'm not sure how to format the code in these comments!

Comment: @Dave you can't nicely format; edit your question to provide these details. You can only use the `Tilde` key (above TAB) to highlight code in comments.

Comment: Hey @Wal Thanks for that! That's much better! :)

Comment: @Dave post your `ValidateUpdatesMessageRequest ` and `Response` classes. How big is the message? Consider making the call synchronous (or on a dedicated separate thread you control) and seeing what the stacktrace looks like for 'bad' calls.

Comment: I know this is a couple of years later, but I've only recently encountered a similar problem. @Dave, I'd like to know if you continued to see this problem related to VM's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually now resolved my issue.

I thought I would post my solution for anyone else who might be experiencing the same problem.

At the end of my method which calls the async method:-

```
_serviceClient.ProcessUpdatesAsync(request);
```

I had a

```
CleanUp()
```

which made a call to

```
_serviceClient.CloseAsync();
```

So this was being closed before the service method could be run.

I simply took the

```
CleanUp()
```

out of the orginial method call to the service and placed it in the event completed method, this way the async thread is closed on completion. 
Seems so obvious now!

Thank you for all of your suggestions and input, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 basic reasons for this happening:

1. The services crashes and therefore the reply is never sent. Check logs on server side.
2. There is a network problem that is stopping the call from coming back. Try monitoring the network traffic with wireshark.
3. The call is coming back, but no one is listening. This happens it the code that was supposed to receive the reply has gone out of scope. Do a code review to look for this problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Shiraz I should have mentioned this, but I have multiple calls to the service throughout my application and from the same class that work absolutely fine. It is only this one call. I have created another method and updated the service with no luck. I have also used Fiddler to monitor the network - I could see that thew call to the service was aborted with no other error message, however I re-sent the EXACT same SOAP message from the Fiddler app and it hit the service! Can't explain it. Any other ideas? Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Shiraz, if the service crashes on the server, then shouldn't there be something written into the event log automatically that a service failed?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. In my case the reason for that was too low **maxArrayLength** value in **readerQuotas** of the binding.